# How to convert /Date(-6847824600000+0530)/ to a Date time

Tags: java

My Web Service returns dates in

```
"dateRequired": "/Date(1357101103000+0530)/",
"etaExport": "/Date(-6847824600000+0530)/",
"etaImport": "/Date(-6847824600000+0530)/",
```

as a json . I want to know the best way to convert these unix dates to DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM format and want to elimitate '/Date'  and '/'. Whats will be the best and efficient way?

Comment: But what do those stribg values mean. What are their corresponding dates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those numbers look like milliseconds since The Epoch followed by a timezone indicator, which is *very odd*, because normally if you're doing milliseconds (or seconds) since The Epoch, you're expressing the date/time in UTC. So the first thing you have to do is look at the documentation for the web service and find out what they mean by the numbers.

Then it's a matter of using a regular expression (or just `String#substring`) to extract the digits, `Long.parseLong` to turn them into a long, instantiating a `Date` object (e.g., `new Date(longNumber)`), and handling whatever timezone math it is the web service is expecting you to do. For that last bit, within the JDK you'll want a `Calendar`, or if you want something a bit easier to work with and more powerful, a lot of people like [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: My web service written in WCF and um returning a C# DatetTime object .  I think they are Milliseconds.

Comment: @Kalanamith: Yes, that part was clear. What's not clear is the timezone thing. Again, usually Epoch values (of either kind) are invariant, expressed in UTC. Perhaps the goal is to say that the time should be expressed in +0530 -- e.g., that your actual first value `1357101103000` is Jan 02 2013 04:31:43 UTC, but you should show it as Jan 02 2013 10:01:43 +0530, or something like that.

Comment: Well I didn't intentionally add the time zone. It comes automatically . My Datetime value in the database look like this "'2012-10-31 20:48:47.287'" and reading and serializing .

Answer (score 1):

Hi Though the above answer is right but as an alternative to this you can use the below method

first extract the long datetime from the json using the below method.

```
      String JsonDate = jsonGroup.getString("Date");

        int idx1 = JsonDate.indexOf("(");
        int idx2 = JsonDate.indexOf("+");

        if (idx1 > 0 && idx1 < idx2 && idx2 < JsonDate.length()) {
            String s = JsonDate.substring(idx1 + 1, idx2);  
        }
```

Once you have the date you can convert Long to Date

```
    if (!s.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
        Long date1 = Long.parseLong(s);
        Date dt1 = new Date(date1);

        holder.TxtPunchoutDate.setText(getDateCurrentTimeZone(dt1));
    }
```

And the set the From Date to UTC and Then Convert it back to Local Time as below

```
public static String getDateCurrentTimeZone(Date dt) {
    try {
        //Convert DATE to UTC DATETIME
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss aa ");
         simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        //simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
         //Convert to LocalDATE from UTC
         Date fromGmt = new Date(dt.getTime() + TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(dt.getTime()));

                    return new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss aa").format(fromGmt).toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return "";
}
```

As said earlier this is an alternative and not a proper way to do it. Though if someone would like to refactor this, please you all are always welcome.

Thanks